# C++ program ending too early

Tags: c++

I am very new to c++, and i have written up this piece of code. Which is designed to go in this order..
1. Asks for name then welcomes the person
2. asks for their weapon of choice
3. picks a random number and damages a panda

I have had all 3 of these steps working. Then i decided maybe i could change the range of my random number, by using variables in my rand() functions parenthesis. That did not work as planned, so i tried reverting back. Thanks in advance to any help received. I wouldnt have any idea how i could search for this through the internet, so i came here.. Hoping someone could spot my issue. I am using netbeans IDE.

My issue:
it firstly asks for my name, then i input my name and it welcomes me. But then it finishes the code. Before even attempting the rest of the code. My thoughts are that i obviously missed something i should have changed back.

```
Welcome to panda hunter! Please enter your name: Darryl
Welcome!, Darryl!

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3s)
```

But i have looked over it many many times and cannot spot anything wrong. Also my thoughts are that there is something wrong with this line, because this is where it fails to do and get further:

```
    cout << "Pick your weapon of choice! Then press enter to attack: ";
```

.  Here is the whole files contents:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

string getName(){
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    return name;
}
string weaponChoice(){
    string weapon;
    cin >> weapon;
    return weapon;
}
int rand(){
    int damagePanda = rand() % 20 + 1;
    return damagePanda;
}
int main() {

    srand(time(0));
    int pandaHealth = 100;
    int userHealth = 100;   


    cout << ("Welcome to panda hunter! Please enter your name: ");
    cout << "Welcome!, " << getName() << "!" << endl;
    cout << "Pick your weapon of choice! Then press enter to attack: ";
    cout << "You surprise the panda with your " << weaponChoice() << ", dealing " <<   rand() << " damage!";
    pandaHealth = pandaHealth - rand();
    cout << "Panda has " << pandaHealth << " health remaining";

    char f;
    cin >> f;
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: That `getName` function looks really strange.

Comment: The missing endl. I am not in C++, but maybe `cout << flush` on some platforms.

Comment: You need to flush the output buffer. Tag on `<< std::endl` to the end of each line sent to `std::cout`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int rand(){
    int damagePanda = rand() % 20 + 1;
    return damagePanda;
}
```

Recursive call. You are probably blowing your stack here.

The compiler should have warned you here! Not sure why it didn't.

Change to

```
int myrand(){
    int damagePanda = rand() % 20 + 1;
    return damagePanda;
}
```

Also change

```
cout << "You surprise the panda with your " 
<< weaponChoice() << ", dealing " <<   rand() << " damage!";
```

to

```
cout << "You surprise the panda with your "  
<< weaponChoice() << ", dealing " <<   myrand() << " damage!";
```

This also probably needs to change

```
pandaHealth = pandaHealth - rand();
```

This last change probably depends on your application logic - I haven't tried to understand it.

Comment: +1 Nice catch. Though I don't think I've seen a "[possible] infinite recursive call" error before.

Comment: You should also store the myrand() result in an int instead of calling it twice, so that you use the same value for cout and for the actual damage calculation.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you very much. Yes.. Compiler should have said something but apparently it doesnt want to. I have also added the bit which Captain said '<< std::endl'   Thank you very much for all help received. Will mark this as the answer!

Comment: Thank you also matthiew, do you mean like this : int randomNumber = myrand(); making it call that. then later when i want another random number, i could call that function again on that int?

Comment: @Darryl I think Mathiew is suggesting that if you need only 1 random number - you need to call the function just once and store it's value and reuse it - of course - if you want to 2 random numbers - you will need to repeat the call like you have done. However we don't know your program logic - so we don't know how many random numbers you need.

Comment: @Dukeling - possibly a warning for redefining a function, though, particularly a standard function such as `rand`? I can't say I've noticed that happen either, though. And even with `rand` hidden, the standard version is still accessible as `std::rand`, so maybe it's not that strange.

Comment: @user93353 - that shouldn't happen because even after `using namespace`, the standard `rand` function is still `std::rand` - you just get the convenience of not having to type the `std::`. When you call it, the compiler adds back the `std::` and [mangles it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). The user-defined `rand` was never in the `std` namespace, so gets a different mangled name.

Comment: @Steve314 He is #including `stdlib.h` and `cstdlib` - so the unmangled `rand` may also be pulled in based on the link line or any pragmas in the headers.